# Asset Helper Function Not Working Correctly in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-helper

I'm new to MVC and Laravel, and I'm trying to include CSS but getting a 404 error. The URL it's generating is...

`http://localhost/testing_laravel/css/app.css`

If I use the URL this way instead...

`http://localhost/testing_laravel/public/css/app.css`

It works fine.

My question is why do the tutorials and documentation not use '/public'? Is there something I am not aware of? Please guide me on how I should use URLs for assets.

`{{ asset('css/app.css') }}`

Comment: If you need to put **/public** in the URL for it to work, then it sounds like you haven’t set your document root correctly. How are you serving the Laravel application? Using the built-in PHP server, Artisan serve, MAMP, other?

Answer (score 1):

The asset() helper prepends the base URL (http://localhost/testing_laravel) to the given path `'css/app.css'`. Within the Laravel directory structure, these assets live in the `/public` folder and Laravel knows that.

When you create your virtual host for your Laravel install you need to make the */public* directory the root. Or, try `php artisan serve`.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the port http://localhost:8000/testing_laravel/css/app.css

Just open command line & point to root of your project, Then run php artisan serve.

This is the proper way.

{{ asset('css/app.css') }} will point to the public directory